# Grouping duplicate match pairs into a single group - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, database-cursor

First post on here!

What im looking to understand is how can I assign different pairings of duplicates with an overall group ID in SQL Server?

For example I have the following table:

```
Test | ID | Pair
A      34    1  
A      84    1
A      34    2
A      88    2
A      36    3
A      88    3
A      40    4
A      42    4
B      34    1
B      98    1
```

What i'd like to be able to do is group them up per test with the notion of "X matches to Y, but Y also matches to Z therefore X also matches to Z"?? So I get the something like:

```
Test | ID | NewGroupID
A      34    1
A      84    1
A      34    1
A      88    1
A      36    1
A      88    1
A      40    2
A      42    2
B      34    1
B      98    1
```

You notice that in the example above, for Test A 34 matches 84 and 34 matches 88, but 88 matches 36 also, so the ID's of 34,84,88,36 are all one group. 
ID 34 also matches ID 98, however this is for Test B so it is in a fresh group for that Test set.

I'm thinking I might I need to use a cursor to loop through?

Really would appreciate any input from you all.
Thanks
Tom

Comment: To be honest, if I were doing this I would be inclined to have this particular logic in the application layer where you have the benefit of easy access to dictionary structures.  You might be able to do it in SQL but I'm not sure that you would get any significant performance advantage -- and in fact you might wind up costing yourself performance.

Comment: This is a hierarchical or recursive query.  MySQL has little support for this type of data structure.  As your tags suggest, you will need a cursor or a loop in a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response both. Any suggestions on approach? I appreciate that this could be fairly performance intensive, and its not ideal, however I would of thought this would be a fairly common problem when it comes to de-duplicating records?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SELECT statement tested in MySQL 5.6.19 that works for your test data.  Note that you'll need a unique or primary key on `test, pair, ID` to ensure that the data is processed in the correct order.  It's not the most elegant code and might be thinned or require tweaking if the test data you gave isn't representative.

```
SET @pg=1;
SET @t='A';
SET @pairs="1";
SELECT  pg.test AS Test,
    p.ID, 
    pg.pair_group AS NewGroupID
FROM
    pairs p
LEFT
JOIN    (
    SELECT  DISTINCT pair,
        pair_group,
        test
    FROM    (
        SELECT  test,
            pair,
            IF(FIND_IN_SET(pair, @pairs), @pg, IF(pair_sets.test = @t, @pg:=@pg+1, @pg:=1)) pair_group,
            @pairs:=pairs,
            @t:=test
        FROM    (
            SELECT  t.test,
                p.pair,
                GROUP_CONCAT(p.pair) pairs
            FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT(test) from pairs ORDER BY test) AS t
            LEFT
            JOIN    pairs p ON p.test = t.test
            GROUP
            BY  t.test,
                p.id
            ORDER
            BY  t.test,
                p.pair,
                pairs
            ) AS pair_sets
        ) AS pair_groups
    ) AS pg ON pg.pair = p.pair AND pg.test = p.test;
```

Comment: Uhm.  Just noticed that this question may be miss-tagged as MySQL rather than SQL Server as per the question.  If it is wrong, then this code won't help you much.